# Using indentation with cucumber docstring

Tags: testing, cucumber

Cucumber strips away indentation from my scenario:

```
    Scenario: view task info with subtasks
    When I run command `-t 1 list`
    Then I should see
    """
    #1 "Test task 1"
    2014-11-12
    Description 1
    Subtasks:
      2014-11-12 Subtask 3 (#3) #this indentation
      2014-11-12 Subtask 1 (#1) #stripped away
    """
```

By experimentation I found, Cucumber cuts out **4** or sometimes **3** leading spaces. So if I need to test two spaces indentation in my code, I need to place six or 5 spaces in Cucumber scenario. It is very strange. Is it correct Cucumber behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber should remove the same amount of indentation that the opening triple quote is using. It often happens that you have different amount of indents if you right-align the keywords like this:

```
Given
 When
 Then
  And
```

The behaviour is now also [documented on the cucumber site](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#doc-strings):

> Each line of the Doc String will be de-indented according to the opening `"""`. Indentation beyond the column of the opening `"""` will therefore be preserved.